# Why can't I change an instance variable from another object

Tags: python, class

Hi I actually found my solution to my problem. However, i just wanna know why can't I change an object instance variable(bye.balance) through another object's instance method(hello.deposit). Instead, I must invoke another instance method through another object instance method. I wanna ask all programming gods here if is there any other method.

Problem: Basically if I change bye.balance through hello.deposit, bye.balance remain 0.

```
class People(object):

    def __init__(self, name , cash, count):
        self.cash=cash
        self.name=name
        self.count=count
        
    def __str__(self):       
        rep=str(self.count) + '\t'+ self.name
        return rep
    
    def deposit(self, dep_amount, account):
        self.cash-=dep_amount
        bye.balance+=dep_amount 


        
class Account(object):
    
    def __init__(self, name, count, balance=0):
        self.name=name
        self.count=count
        self.balance=balance
        
    def __str__(self):
        rep=str(self.count)+'\t'+'account by '+self.name
        return rep

    ##def add(self, dep):
        ##self.balance+=dep

hello=People('cz', 1000, 0)
bye=Account('cz', 0)
dep=int(input('dep amount enter pls'))
hello.deposit(dep, bye.balance)
print(hello.cash, bye.balance)
hello.cash=12345
print(hello.cash)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```py
hello.deposit(dep, bye)
```

and the deposit method could be:

```py
    def deposit(self, dep_amount, account):
        self.cash -= dep_amount
        account.balance += dep_amount
```

Comment: oh wow, i thought i could let self.balance=account then from there it will do the math! Thanks! But may I ask if you know the logical reason why i cant let self.balance as the positional argument for account. when i am using the hello.deposit method

Comment: Its because an `int` is immutable in python, so `account += dep_amount` won't change `bye.balance` when you call `hello.deposit(dep, bye.balance)`. My implementation of `deposit()` has `account.balance += dep_amount` which reassigns a new `int` value to `account.balance`.